# Values of integral as a last row in table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, integral

Is it possible to calculate integrals from data frame in R?

Example.

```
t <- data.frame(x1 = c(200),
           x2 = c(2),
           x3 = c(1:500))
```

If t is table, is it possible to generate new column with integral results like with other operations?

I tried with this code, but it didn't work.

```
Func <- function(z) {(t$x1+t$x2+t$x3)*z}

t$new <- integrate(Func, lower = 1, upper = 2)
```

Comment: Reading throw the documentation on this function `integrate()`, this is what I found: the function must be `an R function taking a numeric first argument and returning a numeric vector of the same length.` Your function takes a number and gives back a 500-elements long vector.

Comment: How was your function supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

Func <- function(z,t) {t*z}

t %>%  rowwise %>% 
       mutate(new = integrate(function(z) Func(z,x1+x2+x3), lower = 1, upper = 2)$value )

# A tibble: 500 x 4
# Rowwise: 
      x1    x2    x3   new
   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1   200     2     1  305.
 2   200     2     2  306.
 3   200     2     3  308.
 4   200     2     4  309 
 5   200     2     5  310.
 6   200     2     6  312 
 7   200     2     7  314.
 8   200     2     8  315 
 9   200     2     9  316.
10   200     2    10  318 
# ... with 490 more rows
```

Comment: You forgot to rewrite the function `Func`, it now takes 2 arguments and though equivalent the formula is different.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way.
Rewrite the function to take an extra argument, the 3-dim vector `X`, corresponding to each row of the table `t`. Then compute the integrals in an `apply` loop over the rows of `t`.

```
Func <- function(z, X) {
  x1 <- X[[1]]
  x2 <- X[[2]]
  x3 <- X[[3]]
  (x1 + x2 + x3)*z
}

t$new <- apply(t, 1, function(x){
  integrate(Func, lower = 1, upper = 2, X = x)$value
})

head(t)
#   x1 x2 x3   new
#1 200  2  1 304.5
#2 200  2  2 306.0
#3 200  2  3 307.5
#4 200  2  4 309.0
#5 200  2  5 310.5
#6 200  2  6 312.0
```

If you are not very comfortable with `*apply` loops, here is an equivalent `for` loop.

```
t$new <- NA
for(i in seq_len(nrow(t))){
  t$new[i] <- integrate(Func, lower = 1, upper = 2, X = t[i, 1:3, drop = TRUE])$value
}
```

The output is the same as above.

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach to @Waldi's, but recovering all the information from the call to `integrate`...

First, define a function to convert an `integrate` object to a list (since there isn't a built-in version).

```
as.list.integrate <- function(x) {
  list(
    value=x$value,
    abs.error=x$abs.error,
    subdivisions=x$subdivisions,
    message=x$message,
    call=x$call
  )
}
```

Now do the integration.

```
t %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(new=list(as.list(integrate(function(z) {(x1+x2+x3)*z}, 1, 2)))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(new, simplify=TRUE)
# A tibble: 500 x 8
      x1    x2    x3 value abs.error subdivisions message call      
   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>     <dbl>        <int> <chr>   <list>    
 1   200     2     1  305.  3.38e-12            1 OK      <language>
 2   200     2     2  306.  3.40e-12            1 OK      <language>
 3   200     2     3  308.  3.41e-12            1 OK      <language>
 4   200     2     4  309   3.43e-12            1 OK      <language>
 5   200     2     5  310.  3.45e-12            1 OK      <language>
 6   200     2     6  312   3.46e-12            1 OK      <language>
 7   200     2     7  314.  3.48e-12            1 OK      <language>
 8   200     2     8  315   3.50e-12            1 OK      <language>
 9   200     2     9  316.  3.51e-12            1 OK      <language>
10   200     2    10  318   3.53e-12            1 OK      <language>
```